# Bigquery - Select a column with not grouping them in group by clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having day-wise tables with google analytics data that is split based on device_category(desktop/mobile/tablet) and user_type(new user/returning user).

My requirement is, to query for the top-performing product in the month and just know the type of device and user. I do not want to group them based on device_category, user_type.

When excluding them from my query is gives an error saying - "**Query error: SELECT list expression references column device_category which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:21]**"

QUERY THAT DOES NOT WORK(this is my requirement)

```
 SELECT
  month, 
  year, 
  device_category, 
  user_type, 
  product_name, 
  round(sum(item_revenue),2) as item_revenue 
FROM 
  `ProjectName.DatasetName.GA_REPORT_3_*` 
where 
  _table_suffix between '20201101' and '20210131' 
  and channel_grouping = 'Organic Search' 
group by 
  month, 
  year, 
  channel_grouping, 
  product_name 
order by 
  item_revenue desc;
```

QUERY THAT WORKS

```
SELECT 
  month, 
  year, 
  device_category, 
  user_type, 
  product_name, 
  round(sum(item_revenue),2) as item_revenue 
FROM 
  `ProjectName.DatasetName.GA_REPORT_3_*` 
where 
  _table_suffix between '20201101' and '20210131' 
  and channel_grouping = 'Organic Search' 
group by 
  month, 
  year, 
  channel_grouping, 
  product_name, 
  device_category, 
  user_type 
order by 
  item_revenue desc;
```

Sample Data

[image: sample data]

I know in regular SQL workbenches we can select a Column in SQL not in Group By clause, but the same does not work for my issue on Bigquery.

Could you help me with a workaround for this.

Comment: Sample data along with formatting your queries such that others can read them would be very helpful here.

Comment: If you don't include `user_type` or `device_category` in the grouping this means that your calculation `sum(item_revenue)` will sum "over the top of them". Meaning, it will include multiple `user_types` and `device_category` in the `sum(item_revenue)` calculation. So if you select them, but don't group by them, what values would you expect to see in these columns? There will be multiple values for them in each row... I suggest that you go through the exercise of trying to create a spreadsheet with the results you want, then you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can envelope `device_category` and `user_type` with [ANY_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#any_value) or `MAX` or `MIN`:

```
 SELECT
  month, 
  year, 
  ANY_VALUE(device_category), 
  ANY_VALUE(user_type), 
  product_name, 
  round(sum(item_revenue),2) as item_revenue 
FROM 
  `ProjectName.DatasetName.GA_REPORT_3_*` 
where 
  _table_suffix between '20201101' and '20210131' 
  and channel_grouping = 'Organic Search' 
group by 
  month, 
  year, 
  channel_grouping, 
  product_name 
order by 
  item_revenue desc;
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me, thanks to help us. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
  x.month, 
  x.year, 
  x.device_category, 
  x.user_type, 
  x.product_name, 
  ROUND(SUM(x.item_revenue),2) as item_revenue 
FROM 
 (SELECT
    month,
    year,
    device_category,
    user_type,
    product_name,
    item_revenue
  FROM `ProjectName.DatasetName.GA_REPORT_3_*` 
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20201101' and '20210131' 
  AND channel_grouping = 'Organic Search'
 ) x 
GROUP BY 
  x.month, 
  x.year,  
  x.product_name, 
  x.device_category, 
  x.user_type 
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(x.item_revenue),2) DESC;
```